# Providing default value on typesafe config getters

Tags: scala, refactoring, typesafe

So I am having multiple occurrences of similar snippets in my code:

```
val optionValue = try {
      Some(config.getString(key))
    } catch {
      case _: Missing => None
    }
```

I want to somehow eliminate this duplicates from my code. I know that typesafe provides a way to give a fallback config file to provide default config values. However, in my case, I am not having any default values for some properties. They are optional properties.

What will be the most optimal way to refactor this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using Scala, and assuming you are ok with using implicits, I would go with the recommended approach of using an enrichment class which allows you to keep your `Option` syntax.

Example config.

```
existent.sample.string="I exist!"
existent.sample.boolean=true
```

Example enrichment class.

```
package config

import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigException}

object MyConfig {

  implicit class RichConfig(val config: Config) extends AnyVal {
    def optionalString(path: String): Option[String] = if (config.hasPath(path)) {
      Some(config.getString(path))
    } else {
      None
    }

    def optionalBoolean(path: String): Option[Boolean] = if (config.hasPath(path)) {
      Some(config.getBoolean(path))
    } else {
      None
    }

    // An example of using the exception approach - but less efficient than using hasPath
    def optionalString2(key: String): Option[String] = try {
      Some(config.getString(key))
    } catch {
      case _: ConfigException => None
    }

  }
}
```

Note that it is better to use `hasPath` (over using a `Try`) to check if a key exists in your scenario rather than having the JVM create an exception which should be of no interest for optional config. which is allowed not to exist.

Demo.

```
import com.typesafe.config._

object ConfigTest extends App {

  import MyConfig._

  val conf = ConfigFactory.load

  val optionalString = conf.optionalString("existent.sample.string")
  val optionalStringNone = conf.optionalString("non-existent.sample.string")

  println(s"String config value: $optionalString")
  println(s"Optional (non-existent) String config value: $optionalStringNone")

  val optionalBoolean = conf.optionalBoolean("existent.sample.boolean")
  val optionalBooleanNone = conf.optionalBoolean("non-existent.sample.boolean")

  println(s"Boolean config value: $optionalBoolean")
  println(s"Optional (non-existent) String config value: $optionalBooleanNone")

}
```

Prints.

```
// String config value: Some(I exist!)
// Optional (non-existent) String config value: None
// Boolean config value: Some(true)
// Optional (non-existent) String config value: None
```

The [docs](https://github.com/lightbend/config#how-to-handle-defaults)

Answer (score 9):

This is not how the library works, according https://github.com/lightbend/config#how-to-handle-defaults.

You should use `withFallback` method to provide a clean configuration.

Answer (score 4):

From Jacko's response, I would prefer to simplify the code and avoid copy&pasting the `hasPath` method for each type.

```
  implicit class RichConfig(val config: Config) extends AnyVal {

    private def getOptional[T](path: String, get: String => T): Option[T] = {
      if (config.hasPath(path)) {
        Some(get(path))
      } else {
        None
      }
    }

    def optionalString(path: String): Option[String] = getOptional(path, config.getString)

    def optionalInt(path: String): Option[Int] = getOptional(path, config.getInt)

    def optionalDouble(path: String): Option[Double] = getOptional(path, config.getDouble)

    def optionalBoolean(path: String): Option[Boolean] = getOptional(path, config.getBoolean)

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

config.hasPath('sample.property') will tell you if the property exists.

Comment: This can be posted as comment

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and this is my solution, hope you like it:

```
Try(key).map(config.getString).map(Some(_)).getOrElse(None)
```